# ul список не выстраивается рядом с background-image

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, ul

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("../images/pepsi.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 80px;
  width: 78px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu>ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lika</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Мешает height, заданный для background-image, но почему?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, для навигации лучше использовать элемент nav, вот попробуйте так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="logo"><a href="#"></a></div>
    <nav class="header-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Добавив свойство float меню будет рядом с лого, [webref.ru](https://webref.ru/css/float)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: url(../images/pepsi.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.header-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2b2b2b;
}
.header-menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header-menu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top:  30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url(http://333v.ru/uploads/00/000a7db0d4c688263a3e8d09e1f5fa93.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```